# Python: Print specific numbers from PDF file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

[image: Example of the type of form I have]

I have a PDF form with multiple fields. I want to scrape the values (only numbers) from those fields.

I am reading the file using the following code, and I can do 2 things-
1. print the entire file
2. Print only numbers

Is there a way I could print those numbers with their page no, or something along this line so that I can easily separate the numbers I want?

```
  from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
  from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
  from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
  from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


 def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
     resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
     fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
     converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
     page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

     with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
         for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
             page_interpreter.process_page(page)

         text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()


     converter.close()
     fake_file_handle.close()

     if text:
         return text

 import re

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     string = extract_text_from_pdf('PDF.pdf')
     string = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', string)
     print (string)
```

Comment: Is the PDF textual or graphical? (Can you select and copy the numbers in your PDF viewer?)

Comment: @KlausD. It's textual, yes i can select and copy the numbers

Comment: Then open the pdf in an (text) editor, find the number and show us how it looks in the pdf code.

Answer (score 0):

So, if the number you want has a defined number of digits you can use regex. 
Let's say you want the number in the example you've given - 3010405008667
Use: re.compile(r'^[0-9]{13}')
you could do the same for the number of pages
Assuming you have not more that 1000 pages:
use: re.compile(r'^[0-9]{1-4}')

Comment: yes i have fixed number of digits, so do you mean something like this?
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = extract_text_from_pdf('PDF.pdf')
    string = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{13}')
    print (string)